# Vertical Table Header Cell Renderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I used the Vertical Table Header Cell Renderer that is available in this site [here](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/vertical-table-header-cell-renderer/)
It works great for me but I need a clue on how can I have in some headers that are vertically aligned multiple rows like this you can see in the image of the example (Coordinate Geometry). I tried to set the strings with the appropriate \n character but I think my approach is very simplistic and wrong.
Please keep it simple. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Joop answer, I made this. Instead of changing the label directly you can keep your `\n`.

In your file `DefaultTableHeaderCellRenderer.java`, replace `getTableCellRendererComponent` with this method :

```
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
              boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

          String str = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(str));
            String line;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<HTML>");
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line).append("<br/>");
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            sb.append("</HTML>");
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, sb,
                isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        JTableHeader tableHeader = table.getTableHeader();
        if (tableHeader != null) {
          setForeground(tableHeader.getForeground());
        }
        setIcon(getIcon(table, column));
        setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
        return this;
      }
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you want label to be center use this in `while` : `sb.append("<CENTER>").append(line).append("</CENTER>");`

Answer (score 4):

In front put `<html>` to make it HTML text, and use `<br>` (line break) instead of `\n`.

Comment: Thank you! I saw this solution in some search but I was not sure if I can implement it on java applications or on web pages only.

Comment: Thank you! Works really as I wanted.

Comment: Good one! I made a method to keep it "invisible" if you are interested.

Comment: One more question! How can I align them now on center those lines?

Comment: You could think of `<p>...</p>` (paragraphs) instead of `<br>`. In general with `<... style="text-align: right; padding-top: 5px">` you can use any CSS styles. Search for SELFHTML or such for pointers.

Comment: Great! Both you helped me a lot!